# problema para mostrar lista de paises en Angular 14

Tags: angular, spring-boot

Hola comunidad soy nuevo en angular y estoy realizando un crud con springboot y angular pero al traer los paises para seleccionar no me muestra en angular los datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo HTML

```
 <label>Pais</label>
  <select name="pais" id="pais" formControlName="nombre" class="form-control">
    <option [value]="item.id" *ngFor="let item of paises">{{ item.nombre }}</option>
  </select>
<button type="submit" class="">Guardar</button>
```

Service

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
 import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


 @Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
 }) 
 export class PaisesService {

 private API_SERVER = " ";

constructor(
  private httpClient: HttpClient
 ) { }


 public findAll(): Observable<any>{
   return this.httpClient.get(this.API_SERVER)
  }
 }
```

---

component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { EstadosService } from "./services/estados/estados.service"
import { PaisesService } from "./services/paises/paises.service"
import { PersonaService } from "./services/persona/persona.service"

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

 personaForm! : FormGroup;
 paises!: any;

constructor(
public fb: FormBuilder,
public estadoService: EstadosService,
public paisesService: PaisesService,
public personaServie: PersonaService
) {

 }
ngOnInit(): void {

this.personaForm = this.fb.group({
  nombre: ["", Validators.required],
  apellido: ["", Validators.required],
  edad: ["", Validators.required],
  pais: ["", Validators.required],
  estado: ["", Validators.required],
});;

this.paisesService.findAll().subscribe(resp =>{
  this.paises = resp;
  console.log(resp);
  },
    error => { console.error(error) }
  )

 }

   
}
```

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el error que me sale pero no se si tenga que ver  con no mostrar los datos,desde el back los trae pero en angular no muesta nada